# ASP.NET MVC - How to set default value in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a field in MS SQL that has bit as data type as show below.

[MS SQL Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJlxV.png)

In ASP.NET MVC, I want to set a value for it and make it hidden.

```
public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "True" } })
```

However, it is not working.

I have these questions:

1. How do I write bit data type in ASP.NET MVC
2. How do I write the default value in the View

Comment: Never set the `value` attribute when using `HtmlHelper` methods. You set the value of `EmailConfirmed` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view, and then its just `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmailConfirmed)` - setting a class name is pointless since its hidden

Comment: But why are you including that property in the view (a malicious user could easily modify it)

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of option here

● It seems you're using SMSS, so in the Column Properties, you can use Default Value

[image]

and set it to 1.

● You can set the value in the constructor.

```
//C# 5 or earlier
public YourConstructor()
{
    EmailConfirmed = true;
}

// or (C# 6 and +)
public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; } = true;
```

So you don't need to force any `@Value` in your `htmlAttributes`.

**But be careful** : As mentioned in comments, you shouldn't use these solutions because any malicious user may alter your view. If you want to post `true` systematically, just don't do anything in your view and add true to your property directly in your `HttpPost` action.